# How to get next n lines from in a file when a line is found

Tags: python, iterator

While reading a file in python, I was wondering how to get the next `n` lines when we encounter a line that meets my condition.

Say there is a file like this

```
mangoes:
1 2 3 4 
5 6 7 8
8 9 0 7
7 6 8 0
apples:
1 2 3 4
8 9 0 9
```

Now whenever we find a line starting with mangoes, I want to be able to read all the next 4 lines.

I was able to find out how to do the next immediate line but not next `n` immediate lines

```
if (line.startswith("mangoes:")):
            print(next(ifile))  #where ifile is the input file being iterated over
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just repeat what you did

```
if (line.startswith("mangoes:")):
    for i in range(n):
        print(next(ifile))
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's a huge file and you don't want to read all lines into memory at once you could do something like this

```py
n = 4

with open(fn) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for idx, ln in enumerate(lines):
    if ln.startswith("mangoes"):
        break

mangoes = lines[idx:idx+n]
```

This would give you a list of the `n` number of lines, including the word `mangoes`. if you did `idx=idx+1` then you'd skip the title too.

Answer (score 1):

With [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) feature:

```
from itertools import islice

with open('yourfile') as ifile:
    n = 4
    for line in ifile:
        if line.startswith('mangoes:'):
            mango_lines = list(islice(ifile, n))
```

From your input sample the resulting `mango_lines` list would be:

```
['1 2 3 4 \n', '5 6 7 8\n', '8 9 0 7\n', '7 6 8 0\n']
```